# Find a string in csv and only work on that line

Tags: batch-file, csv, cmd, find, findstr

I have a batch file that needs to look through a csv and find one line based on a unique string, that is a variable mixture of letters and numbers, that should be input by the user (most likely scanned by a barcode).

The current csv set up is as per below:

School,computerid,Model,Serial,User,Access

These are headings and aren't the actual data. The variable that will be searched for is the `WorkstationID`. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

My entire code is below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Echo What is the students computer name?
set /p computerid=
findstr /i "%computerid%" "AccessElevations.csv" > %temp%\computer.txt
pause
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (%temp%\computer.txt) DO (
set school=%%a
set Model=%%c
set Serial=%%d
set user=%%e
set access=%%f
```

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: It's expected that you show some evidence of having tried to figure out the problem before asking questions here.

Comment: Sorry everyone, very new to the website, I have added in the entire script for you all now.

Comment: You'd be better off only adding relevant sections of the code.

Comment: For some reason I am getting an output into the %temp%\computer.txt file as Echo is off, press any key to continue.

Comment: What did you call the batch file?  Try calling it `abc.bat` and see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: Hi @foxidrive i called it test1.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue in the end thank you everyone for your help though. I fixed it by changing the format to .txt of the accesselevations.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - To adapt to comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "inputFile=AccessElevations.csv"
    set "computerID="
    set /p "computerID=What is the students computer name? "
    if not "%computerID%"=="" for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (
        'findstr.exe /i /r /c:"^[^,]*,%computerID%," "%inputFile%"'
    ) do (
        set "school=%%a"
        set "model=%%c"
        set "serial=%%d"
        set "user=%%e"
        set "access=%%f"
    )

    echo school : %school%
    echo model  : %model%
    echo serial : %serial%
    echo user   : %user%
    echo access : %access%

    rem clean
    endlocal
```

If a computerID is provided, `findstr` is used to find this computerID in the second field (skip the line until the first comma, then the computerID, then a comma) of the indicated file. If a line is found, `for` command will split it using a comma as a delimiter.

Comment: Hi @MC ND, I would really prefer that it were in line with my code and not written in a different style such as using _user and _access etc. I don't need the entire code re-written I just would like to know how to find a line based on a short string such as workstation name, and then use that line only.

Comment: @Random206, In line with your code. Removed underscores and comments. Hope now you see better how it works. But temporary intermediate file also removed. Not needed. If a match is found, directly split it. Anyway if you prefer to use intermediate files, do it, it is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

If this deosn't help then please explain what problem you are having and what the error message is.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Echo What is the students computer name?
set /p computerid=
findstr /i "%computerid%" "AccessElevations.csv" > "%temp%\computer.txt"
pause
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in ("%temp%\computer.txt") DO (
   set school=%%a
   set Model=%%c
   set Serial=%%d
   set user=%%e
   set access=%%f
)
```

Comment: I was able to fix this issue in the end thank you everyone for your help though. I fixed it by changing the format to .txt of the accesselevations.csv file...not really sure why this worked, as I thought cmd could read csv files.